# Does QAbstractSocket::waitForDisconnected impose a race condition?

Tags: qt

Here is the outline of my QThread subclass which is created per-connection by my QTcpServer subclass

```
void
Socket :: run ()
{
    QTcpSocket socket;

    if (false == socket .setSocketDescriptor (m_sd))
    {
         error ();
         return;
    }

    do_stuff ();

    socket .disconnectFromHost ();
    socket .waitForDisconnected ();
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
QAbstractSocket::waitForDisconnected() is not allowed in UnconnectedState
```

Huh? This code is lifted from [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html). Elsewhere I have seen this:

```
socket .disconnectFromHost ();

if (QAbstractSocket :: ConnectedState == socket .state ())
    socket .waitForDisconnected ();
```

Isn't this a race condition? If it's not a race condition then it's not an asynchronous process, in that universe `disconnectFromHost` would always succeed and `waitForDisconnected` would be redundant. Right?

What is the correct usage of these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a case where `QAbstractSocket::disconnectFromHost` will disconnect immediately. If you look at the [source code](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/network/socket/qabstractsocket.cpp.html#_ZN15QAbstractSocket18disconnectFromHostEv), there is this part:

```
...
    // Wait for pending data to be written.
    if (d->socketEngine && d->socketEngine->isValid() && (d->writeBuffer.size() > 0
        || d->socketEngine->bytesToWrite() > 0)) {
        ...
        if (d->writeBuffer.size() == 0 && d->socketEngine->bytesToWrite() > 0) {
        if (!d->disconnectTimer) {
            d->disconnectTimer = new QTimer(this);
            connect(d->disconnectTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this,
                SLOT(_q_forceDisconnect()), Qt::DirectConnection);
        }
        if (!d->disconnectTimer->isActive())
            d->disconnectTimer->start(2000);
        }
        d->socketEngine->setWriteNotificationEnabled(true);

#if defined(QABSTRACTSOCKET_DEBUG)
        qDebug("QAbstractSocket::disconnectFromHost() delaying disconnect");
#endif
        return;
    } else {
#if defined(QABSTRACTSOCKET_DEBUG)
        qDebug("QAbstractSocket::disconnectFromHost() disconnecting immediately");
#endif
    }
}

SocketState previousState = d->state;
d->resetSocketLayer();
d->state = UnconnectedState;
...
```

So if there is no pending data to be written, it will disconnect immediately.

Comment: Let's assume `do_stuff()` writes data, so we can't assume this case applies, but thanks for looking in detail.

Comment: @spraff Even if `do_stuff()` writes data, you can't assume that there is still some pending data to be written when you call `disconnectFromHost`. All data can be written when calling `write`. You'd have to check how many bytes were written and compare it to the size of the data that should be written to be sure.

Comment: If it *happens* to be that no pending data is to be written then fine, but we just got lucky and hit a simpler path, but the code needs to work in cases where all the data *hasn't* been written, which is reasonably likely.

Comment: @spraff If there is pending data, then it will not disconnect immediately. In this case you should not get that warning about calling `waitForDisconnected` in unconnected state.

Comment: So you're saying that although there may theoretically be a race condition between `if(QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState==socket.state())` and `socket.waitForDisconnected(); ` in practice it won't matter, is that it?

Comment: @spraff Well there is no race condition, unless you are accessing the same `QTcpSocket` instance from two different threads, which is not supported. Checking the connection state before calling `waitForDisconnected` should get rid of that warning. The state cannot change between `if(QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState==socket.state())` and `socket.waitForDisconnected();`.